# WPF MVVM Background UIElement doesn't change on NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm, background, datatrigger

First a small word explaining what I want to do.

I'm creating a filter for showing several objects with the same entity type (ProvisionalOrder). This entity has a property DateTime Date. With this Date I want to filter. For example: if the users clicks on date X , the view will display all provisional  orders with date X.

For every date I make a button in my view. I want to set the background of the buttons like this:
OrangeRed = Activated. 
LightSkyBlue = Not activated.

When I'm starting the program the background is fine. But if I click on the button, the background doesn't change to the color it should be.

Something wrong with the datatrigger?

View:

```
 <!-- Grid with date buttons -->
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DatePairs}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Path=Key}" 
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type this:ProvisionalOrderSelecterView} }, 
                                Path=DataContext.FilterDateCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Key}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
<!-- End Grid with date buttons -->
```

Code-Behind View:

```
public partial class ProvisionalOrderSelecterView : UserControl
{
    public ProvisionalOrderSelecterView(ProvisionalOrderSelecterViewModel provisionalOrderSelecterViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = provisionalOrderSelecterViewModel;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ProvisionalOrderSelecterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private RelayCommand<DateTime> filterDateCommand; 

    private SortedDictionary<DateTime, bool> datePairs;
    private ObservableCollection<ProvisionalOrder> provisionalOrders; 

    public ProvisionalOrderSelecterViewModel(ObservableCollection<ProvisionalOrder> provisionalOrders)
    {
        this.ProvisionalOrders = provisionalOrders;

        if(datePairs == null)
            datePairs = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, bool>();

        FillDates();
        datePairs.Add(DateTime.Now.Date, true);

    }

    void FillDates()
    {
        var copy = datePairs;
        datePairs = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, bool>();

        foreach (var provisionalOrder in this.provisionalOrders.Where(provisionalOrder => !datePairs.ContainsKey(provisionalOrder.Date.Date)))
        {
            datePairs.Add(provisionalOrder.Date.Date, copy.ContainsKey(provisionalOrder.Date.Date) && copy[provisionalOrder.Date.Date]);
        }
    }

    private void ProvisionalOrders_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("ProvisionalOrders");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ProvisionalOrder> ProvisionalOrders
    {
        get { return this.provisionalOrders; }
        set
        {
            this.provisionalOrders = value;
            this.provisionalOrders.CollectionChanged += ProvisionalOrders_CollectionChanged;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProvisionalOrders");
        }
    }

    public SortedDictionary<DateTime, bool> DatePairs
    {
        get { return this.datePairs; }
        set
        {
            this.datePairs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DatePairs");
        }
    } 

    public ICommand FilterDateCommand
    {
        get { return this.filterDateCommand ?? (this.filterDateCommand = new RelayCommand<DateTime>(FilterDate)); }
    }

    void FilterDate(DateTime date)
    {
        datePairs[date] = !datePairs[date];
        OnPropertyChanged("DatePairs");
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members
}
```

**EDIT:  I made a messy solution. If anyone still knows an answer, I would appreciate it if you would share it with stackoverflow.**

Answer:
On my button I made a click event.

```
 private void DateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;

        if (button != null)
        {
            var background = button.Background as SolidColorBrush;

            if (background != null)
            {
                button.Background = background.Color.Equals(Colors.OrangeRed)
                                        ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSkyBlue)
                                        : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.OrangeRed);
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: You've got two problems here. First when you bind to your `Dictionary` to effectively bind to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, bool>>` and [`KeyValuePair`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) is structure, so value type, and as such WPF will copy its value rather then keep reference to it. Also it does not implement `INotyfyPropertyChanged` and you don't/can't change its `Value`

Answer (score 0):

The property 'Value' should change from false to true. You need a way to change the value of 'Value' to true when the button is clicked. You are using it in a trigger, but not binding the 'Value' to anything for it to change. A better solution is to use a togglebutton and bind the ischecked property to 'Value'. Also you need not have 2 triggers.
Check this for toggle button:
[WPF ToggleButton IsChecked Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749107/wpf-togglebutton-ischecked-trigger)

Comment: The property 'Value' is changed with this:
  datePairs[date] = !datePairs[date];

I've read dkozl his answer and the problem is indeed the KeyValuePair. Maybe using a togglebutton is a good solution. I'll check it out. Thanks