# Togglebutton content change in image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I have code in wpf which use **ToggleButton**.

```
<Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="pinButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" MaxWidth="26" Height="26"
                                          Background="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}" Focusable="False"
                                          DockPanel.Dock="Right"  BorderThickness="0" 
                                          OverridesDefaultStyle="False" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}"  FontFamily="Webdings">
            <Label x:Name="Pinback" Background="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}" Width="26" Height="26" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MyBorderBlueGradientBrush}">
                <Label x:Name="Pin"  FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Content="" Width="25" Height="25" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="16" CenterX="29" CenterY="0"></RotateTransform>
                    </Label.RenderTransform>
                </Label>
            </Label>
        </ToggleButton>

    </Grid>
```

When I run this code, I got this window.

[image]

So My question is "How the content change into pin image".When I change the content it convert in other image.

Comment: Could this `Content=""` be your problem?  I removed the `""` from my test projet and the pin disappeared

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override ToggleButton Style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416821/override-togglebutton-style)

Comment: @Gimly this is bug request not 'how to' question, am I correct vikky?

Comment: @LIUFA Well, what vikky is trying to do is clearly the same as the solution given in the SO question that I linked. The approach is different, but the approach in the link is the recommended approach for that kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pin is coming from a character from the `Webdings FontFamily` in your XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="Pin" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Content="" Width="25" 
    Height="25" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Note the `Content` property... obviously, you can't see the character here, because that font is not common on websites. Also note the `FontFamily` declared in the `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="pinButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" MaxWidth="26"
    Height="26" Background="Blue" Focusable="False" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  
    BorderThickness="0" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" BorderBrush="Blue"  
    FontFamily="Webdings">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I have found the whole set of Webdings character set.http://unicode.org/~asmus/web-wing-ding-ext.pdf

Comment: I believe that they're included in the standard fonts on Windows PCs.